# Convert Rails Active Record query 'find' method to 'where' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do I convert this find query method below to use the where method instead (just trying to better myself in rails)?

```
@deals = Deal.find(params[:id])
```

I've tried

```
@deals = Deal.where(deal_id: params[:id])
```

AND

```
@deals = Deal.where("deal_id = params[:id]")
```

But am not getting any results -- I'm receiving undefined method errors and an assortment of other errors. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@deal = Deal.find(params[:id])
```

equivalent

```
@deal = Deal.where(id: params[:id]).first
```

.find() will return an exception if record not exist.

.where().first will return nil if record not exist.

Answer (score 2):

The safe approach is:

```
@deals = Deal.where("deal_id = ?", params[:id])
```

Answer (score 1):

You would make your query like so:

```
@deal = Deal.where(id: params[:id])
```

Comment: To add to @DustinFisher's response, just be wary that `.where` will return a collection instead of a single object.

Comment: hmmm, I tried that and am receiving an undefined method where I output the query in the view. " `title' for #<Deal::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f816122c0b0>". Not sure what could be wrong. For some reason I'm not getting anything from that where query, the find one still works.

Comment: @user1852651 could that potentially be the reason I'm receiving a method error? Because it's giving me a collection rather than one object with all the data?

Comment: Yeah, you would need to do this to get the result: `@deal = Deal.where(id: params[:id]).first`

Comment: Possibly. It's not ideal to use `.where` to locate a record by its primary key. That's what `.find` is for. If you want to just get one record, stick with `.find`. If you want to get more than one record, then use `.where`. You could retrieve just one record with `.where`, but you would have to access properties using `.first`, like so: `@deal.first.some_column_name`.

Comment: @DustinFisher yeah that worked with .first. Thanks, basically I learned to simply stick to find for a single object :D